# нарисовать движения точки внутри квадрата через канвас в html

Tags: html5, canvas, курсор

Как нарисовать движение точки внутри квадрата через канвас в html?

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем именно вы видите проблему, как её воспроизвести, что вы хотите получить в результате и т. д.

Answer (score 1):

Накидал пример в
[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3f23423p/%20%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B8)

Более подробней о том как это работает можно прочитать в статье [www.kirupa.com](http://www.kirupa.com/html5/creating_simple_html5_canvas_animation.htm%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%20kirupa.com)

Суть решения сводится к следующему:

1. Рисуем круг в координате x,y
2. По таймауту чистим полотно и перерисовываем точку в уже новых координатах x1, y1

```js
var mainCanvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var mainContext = mainCanvas.getContext('2d');

var canvasWidth = mainCanvas.width;
var canvasHeight = mainCanvas.height;

var rectX = 10,
  rectY = 10;

var positionX = 25,
  positionY = 25,
  radius = 10;

var requestAnimationFrame = window.requestAnimationFrame ||
  window.mozRequestAnimationFrame ||
  window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame ||
  window.msRequestAnimationFrame;

var rectWidth = 300,
  rectHeight = 200;

function drawCircle() {
  mainContext.clearRect(rectX, rectY, rectWidth, rectHeight);

  // color in the background
  mainContext.fillStyle = "#EEEEEE";
  mainContext.fillRect(rectX, rectY, rectWidth, rectHeight);

  // draw the circle
  mainContext.beginPath();

  mainContext.arc(positionX, positionY, radius, 0, Math.PI * 2, false);
  mainContext.closePath();

  // color in the circle
  mainContext.fillStyle = "#006699";
  mainContext.fill();

  if ((positionY + radius) >= rectHeight && positionX > (rectX + radius)) {
    positionX -= 5;
  } else if ((positionX <= (rectX + radius)) && positionY > (rectY + radius)) {
    positionY -= 5;
  } else if (positionX < rectWidth) {
    positionX += 5;
  } else if (positionY <= (rectHeight + rectY)) {
    positionY += 5;
  }

  requestAnimationFrame(drawCircle);


}

drawCircle();
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
```